# URDF spawn into Gazebo world error

Tags: ros, gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**How can I spawn a URDF into a custom Gazebo world, preferably using a launch file?**

My task is to  launch my custom Gazebo world which has a DEM of Mongolia. I also have to spawn a URDF of a robot into
the same Gezebo instance.

For the DEM, I followed [this](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=dem&cat=build_world) tutorial. Which worked well for me. But then I tried the following command to try spawning my robot:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/catkin2_ws/src/my-robot$ rosrun gazebo_ros spawn_model -file urdf/01-myfirst.urdf -urdf -z 1 -model my_test
```

The terminal only shows the following output and nothing else happens:

> SpawnModel script started
> [INFO] [1511782992.386535, 0.000000]: Loading model XML from file
> [INFO] [1511782992.388399, 0.000000]: Waiting for service /gazebo/spawn_urdf_model

When I stop the terminal, i:e Ctrl + C, I get the following output:

```
>     ^CTraceback (most recent call last):
>       File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/gazebo_ros/spawn_model",
> line 313, in <module>
>         sm.callSpawnService()
>       File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/gazebo_ros/spawn_model",
> line 271, in callSpawnService
>         initial_pose, self.reference_frame,
> self.gazebo_namespace)
>       File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gazebo_ros/gazebo_interface.py",
> line 28, in spawn_urdf_model_client
>         rospy.wait_for_service(gazebo_namespace+'/spawn_urdf_model')
>       File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/impl/tcpros_service.py",
> line 159, in wait_for_service
>         raise ROSInterruptException("rospy
> shutdown")
>     rospy.exceptions.ROSInterruptException:
> rospy shutdown
```

**Can anyone help me resolve this issue, please?**

My package has the following structure:

```
.
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── launch
│   └── mongolia.launch
├── mongolia_129.dem
├── mongolia.world
├── package.xml
└── urdf
    └── 01-myfirst.urdf
```

**PS: **

This work fine if I execute:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~/catkin2_ws/src/my-robot$ roslaunch gazebo_ros empty_world.launch
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/276753/urdf-spawn-into-gazebo-world-error/) by [sisko](https://answers.ros.org/users/32731/sisko/) on ROS Answers with karma: 247 on 2017-11-27

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sisko](https://answers.ros.org/users/32731/sisko/) on 2017-11-28**:
Thank you so much. That's what I was missing all along

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2017-11-28**:
Great... I converted my comment to an answer so that this question will show up as having an answer. It would be great if you could accept the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you also run `rosrun gazebo_ros gazebo` in a separate terminal? That node should provide the `/gazebo/spawn_urdf_model` service the `spawn_model` node is waiting on. Note this node is also started in the `empty_world.launch` launch file.

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2017-11-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6